# What are the ways to get authorized access to mlflow through Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, active-directory

What are the ways to get authorized access to mlflow through Azure Active Directory?

Requirements:

- I need to grant access to the mlflow web interface installed on a Ubuntu 16 Virtual Machine in Azure cloud to only allow authorized users.
- Granting access will be done through group membership in Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MLFlow doesn't natively support any authentication schemes and [the recommendation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mlflow-users/E9QW4HdS8a8) is to use a reverse proxy such as Nginx to only forward requests to MLFlow if a valid authentication cookie is provided, redirecting any requests without a cookie or an invalid cookie back to the Identity Provider.

### Azure AD Application Proxy

You can [configure Azure AD Application Proxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy) to add authentication, although you will also need to protect MLFlow from unauthorised access by putting it in a virtual network or creating rules to only accept connections from Azure AD Application Proxy.

### Used managed ML Flow in Azure

There is also the potential of using MLFlow that is part of [Azure Databricks](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/), which probably also includes authentication.

### Nginx

There are [complete instructions](https://www.nginx.com/blog/conditional-access-control-with-microsoft-azure-active-directory/) on setting this up on the Nginx for a generic application. In summary, however, you will need to:

- configure Nginx as a reverse proxy
- prevent access to MLFlow from anything other than Nginx
- create an application in Azure Active Directory for Nginx
- configure Nginx to look for the JWT token and validate it

You would also be able to use other products such as [Google's Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) and [ForgeRock's Identity Gateway](https://www.forgerock.com/platform/identity-gateway).